# Can Visio create a PDF with hyperlinks preserved?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-visio, hyperlink

Can Visio create a PDF with hyperlinks preserved?

My earlier experimenting resulted in me concluding it could not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried with both Visio 2007 and Visio 2010 and when adding a Hyperlink to a shape it and then saving the drawing as PDF resulted in the hyperlink being preserved in the PDF file when viewed with the Adobe Acrobat Reader and Google Chrome.

In Visio 2007 my procedure was

- Draw shape (simple rectangle)
- **Insert** menu > **Hyperlinks**
- In the **Hyperlinks** dialog, enter a URL into the **Address** field, then click **OK**
- **File** menu > **Save As**
- In the **Save As** Dialog, for **Save as type** select "**PDF (*.pdf)**"
- Then open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat or Google Chrome to verify the link works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure none of your Visio ShapeNames have hyphens in them - that had me stumped!

Once I renamed all my shapes both on-page and off-page references worked fine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had real problems with this what I found (Visio 2010) was if I saved it first in the format `"mydocumentname.html".dwg` (the quotation marks are essential) and changed the output file type to `VML` while this publishes the file if you then save as PDF all the links work - hypens and all

I discovered this by accident; as in order to get multiple links to work I had had to save my file in that format. I had published it that way as I couldn't get the links to work, then was trying something different, saved as a PDF and suddenly all the links were working!