# Exported PDFs from Visio 2016 not showing hyperlinks

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-visio, hyperlink, microsoft-visio-2016

I am using Visio 2016, and the PDFs I generate via "save as", "export", or even other 3rd party PDF generation tools (Adobe Acrobat, PDFCreator, etc) do not show the hyperlinks on the objects printed on the PDF.

Any suggestions on how to make the URLs on the PDF clickable? (I can't see them when I wave my mouse over like I can on Visio 2016)

Clarification: [this is how I am making hyperlinks on Visio -- by pressing CTRL+K.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-hyperlink-271FB2A8-4081-47DB-A333-487315C05085?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Different solutions to the same problem: [(1)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/707508-converting-visio-with-hyperlinks-to-pdf-breaks-the-hyperlinks) [(2)](https://superuser.com/questions/278366/can-visio-create-a-pdf-with-hyperlinks-preserved)

Comment: I did (1) to quickly get my project out the door, and (2) doesn't seem to work with Visio 2016 (they tested only Visio 2007/2010, it seems). Thanks for the response.  I will likely purchase one of the tools that is advertised to fix this particular problem.